# Google Drive API Exporting Google Forms 403 Insufficient Permissions

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to export certain files in a user's Google Drive through a service account.  I have downloaded hundreds of files from users without issue except for this one Google Form.  When I try to export it, I get the following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<id>/export?mimeType=application%2Fzip returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.">
```

However when I pull back the capabilities list I get the following:

```
{
   'capabilities':{
      'canAddChildren':False,
      'canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission':False,
      'canChangeViewersCanCopyContent':False,
      'canComment':False,
      'canCopy':True,
      'canDelete':False,
      'canDownload':True,
      'canEdit':False,
      'canListChildren':False,
      'canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive':False,
      'canMoveItemOutOfDrive':False,
      'canReadRevisions':False,
      'canRemoveChildren':False,
      'canRename':False,
      'canShare':False,
      'canTrash':False,
      'canUntrash':False
   }

}
```

I'm very confused because canCopy=True and canDownload=True but I still can't export the file.  Is there any reason this would happen and can I fix it?